# Wordpress Conditional Statement

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Im trying to create a widget that displays a list depending on whether or not the page has children. Here is what my code looks like so far:

```
<?php    
function widget_myHelloWorld() {
    ?>
    <?php if ( is_page() ) { ?>
    <?php
    global $id;
    $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=$id&show_date=modified&date_format=$date_format");
    if ($children) {?>
        <ul>
    <?php echo $children; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php } } ?>
    <?php
    }

    function myHelloWorld_init()
    {
      register_sidebar_widget(__('Sidebar Sub Navigation'), 'widget_myHelloWorld');
    }
    add_action("plugins_loaded", "myHelloWorld_init");
    ?>
```

The `<li>` elements containing the links to sub-pages are successfully displayed, however the  elements are not. Any idea what is going on here?

*Eventually, I need to add some divs and other elements, so simply inserting the extra code as part of the wrap parameter in `wp_list_pages()` is impractical.

Comment: Could you clarify your second to last paragraph?

Comment: "however the elements are not" Witch elements? You could paste a print_r($children) and HTML output that you say is not working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wp_list_pages() will always output the pages list. Even if you try to assign it to a variable. It's the equivalent of `$children = echo 'string';` which isn't going to work.

what you wanna do is define:

```
$children = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID);
```

Then to check it conditionally

```
if (count($children) != 0 ) {
    //this is where the magic happens
}
```